# Is it possible to use a metric (distance) unit in igraph cutoff argument?

Tags: r, spatial, igraph

Newbie igraph user here.  I'm trying to calculate betweenness values for every segment (edge) in a street network. I would ideally like to restrict the calculations so that only paths of less than X metres be considered.  The `igraph::edge.betweenness.estimate` function  has a `cutoff` argument which restricts this for *steps* (*turns*) but I would like to know if it is possible to use a metric distance instead.

So far the closest question I have been able to find is http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2012-11/msg00083.html on the igraph help, and this suggests that it might not be possible.

I have been using my network aspatially, as a simple graph, but have an attribute of street segment length - `LnkLength`.  From reading other StackOverflow posts it is possible to use spatial networks with igraph (with the help of spatial packages).  If LnkLength could be used as a weight for the network would this solve my problem?

If anyone has any ideas I'd be very grateful to hear them.

```
data <- data.frame(
Node1 = as.factor(c(AA, AB, AC, AD, AE, AF, AG, AH, AI, AJ)),
Node2 = as.factor(c(BA, BB, BC, AA, AB, AC, BA, BB, BC, AA)),
LnkLength =as.numeric(c(23.05, 42.81, 77.08, 39.63, 147.87, 56.46, 13.43, 25.53, 197.19, 34.9)))

data.graph <- graph.data.frame(data, directed=FALSE, vertices=NULL)

# attempt to limit the betweeness estimates on 800m
btw.trunc <- edge.betweenness.estimate(d.graph, e=E(d.graph), directed = FALSE, cutoff=20,  weights = NULL)
```

Comment: No, this is not possible currently.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are computing geodesic betweenness scores (e.g. counts of the number of times a shortest path uses a given edge) as opposed to, say current-flow betweenness (which would treat the graph like a network of electrical reisistors).
I think one solution would be to first use the 'distances' function to obtain the matrix of all pairwise distances
e.g.

```
distMat=distances(g,weights=g$LnkLength)
```

Now assuming you have a cutoff dCut, you can then sparsify the matrix

```
distMat[which(distMat>dCut)]=0
distMat=as(distMat,'sparseMatrix')
```

This would allow you to select which pairs of points to consider...

```
fromInds=row(distMat)[which(!distMat==0)]
toInds=col(distMat)[which(!distMat==0)]
```

Assuming there are no one way streets and the LnkLength is not a directed property, then you would only have to consider either the upper or lower triangular portion of the matrix. Since the 'toInds' array will automatically be listed in ascending order, you can accomplish this by taking only the first half of the fromInds and toInds respectively

```
fromInds=fromInds[c(1:(length(fromInds)/2)]
toInds=toInds[c(1:length(toInds)/2)]
```

If your graph is directed (e.g. LnkLength is not the same in both directions or there are one way streets) then you would just leave fromInds and toInds as is.
You would now be ready to start assigning betweenness scores iteratively by looping over the index list and computing shortest_path and using the returned path to increment the betweenness scores of the appropriate edges

```
E(g)$betweenness=0
for(iPair in c(1:length(fromInds)){
 vpath=as.numeric(
        shortest_paths(g,weights=g$LnkLength,output="vpath")$vpath[[1]])
 #need to convert the list of path vertices into a list of edge indices
 pathlist=c(1:(2*length(vpath)-1))
 pathlist[c(1:length(vpath)-1))*2]=vpath[c(2:length(vpath)))]
 pathlist[c(1:length(vpath)-1))*2-1]=vpath[c(1:(length(vpath)-1))]
 eList=get.edge.ids(g,pathlist)
 #increment betweenness scores of edges in eList
 E(g)$betweenness[eList]=E(g)$betweenness+1
}
```

your graph should now have the property 'betweenness' assigned to its edges using a geodesic betweenness metric computed over the subset of paths with a distance of less than 'dCut'

If your graph is quite large, it may be worth while to port the above for loop over to Rcpp, since it could take quite a long time otherwise. But that is a whole new can of worms...